# Detect If Mouse/Keyboard Is Connected

Tags: sdl2

Is there a way to detect if a mouse and keyboard are connected to a device?

Looking through the SDL source code, I can see there are internal functions that could provide this information, but cannot find any public APIs.

The `SDL_GetNumTouchDevices()` function seems to only provide details about touch devices, which I'm assuming includes a touch screen on a mobile device.

The only way I can think of doing this is to detect which events get pumped from SDL, and mark devices as present if a related event gets passed.